# Mysql query to fetch data

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a table "request" with 4 columns namely:

```
1.recId :long primary key
2.interactionId:long
3.requestedBy:boolean
4.requestedType:boolean
```

and data is as follows:
VALUES

```
(185,455699,0,5),
(186,455746,0,1),
(187,455746,1,1),
(188,455752,0,1),
(189,455753,0,1),
(190,455753,1,1),
(191,455754,1,1)
```

i want a query to fetch all the rows where interactionId is same and having requestedBy both 1 and 0 values and requestType=1;

regards,
Nihar

Comment: Posting the expected output for your example data would help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little difficult to understand. I'm assuming you meant this:

> I want a query to fetch all pairs of rows from the request table where:
>
> - the interactionId is same in both rows
> - requestType = 1 for both rows
> - requestedBy is 1 in one row and 0 in the other row

If so, then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM request T1
JOIN request T2
ON T1.interactionId = T2.interactionId
AND T1.requestType = 1
AND T2.requestType = 1
AND T1.requestedBy = 0
AND T2.requestedBy = 1
```